# How to open *.sif files with Mathematica

Tags: import, data, dataset

While I am processing my data collect from an Andor EM-CCD, I find it diffcult to import the file into mathematica. I think mathematica can open this kind of files since that Matlab can open it. So if you have this kind of experience, please help me. Thanks.

Since people have mentioned, there might be a package thing for the .sif file. Does anyone know where to find that ?

.sif files is similiar to ASCII files. Both photos and videos taken by the CCD can be saved as .sif files

Comment: _"I think mathematica can open this kind of files since my friend told me that Matlab can open it."_ does not compute

Comment: It isn't supported if it isn't listed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html). Unfortunately, I don't think SIF is listed. Someone might have [written an import converter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) for SIF, though. You may want to edit your question to ask that specifically.

Comment: @belisarius what i meant was I hope Mathematica can do this job. Cause I don't want to change my previous code into matlab codes

Comment: Perhaps the last program in this page may provide you some relief http://www.physics.ncsu.edu/jet/techdocs/

Comment: @belisarius Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

(Posting this answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered)

You can convert ***.sif** files to ASCII by using the SIFConvert (Win platform) program available for downloading at [**this page**](http://www.physics.ncsu.edu/jet/techdocs/). The authors made it to be able to process sif files with Mathematica.